# Is there a way to handle undefined method of Library of GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, try-catch, dom-events, nosuchmethoderror

If I have a Library : MYLIB

All we know that we can call somelike : `MILIB.declarateMethod();`

If from my client code i call `MILIB.unKnowMethod();` 
it will return some ERROR ...

Is there a way catch this event like
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod
and handle it ???

---UPDATE---

I want catch the call into Library ... 
if i want call `MILIB.Test1()` and `MILIB.Test2()` ,
 i want get

> "Test1"

and

> "Test2"

into `MILIB` Library

Comment: You might want to check this [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries), this will guide you into adding libraries to your Google Apps Script to be able to call functions from that library. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tks for answer. Yes i was read it. But the idea is capture the call to unknow fucntions of Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap it in a `try...catch` block, handle the error as desired in the `catch`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want handle into Library's code... I want catch the call from Library ... if i want call MILIB.Test1() and MILIB.Test2() , i want get "Test1" and "Test2" into Library

Comment: pretty sure you can't do that in javascript but would be interested to find out if you can.

Comment: this is sort of along the lines of what you want to do too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Basic_example